# Submit specific inputs with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="checkbox" value="add" id="checkbox_m">
        <input type="text" value="" id="m">
        <input type="checkbox" value="add" id="checkbox_n">
        <input type="text" value="" id="n">
        <button type="submit" id="button">Send</button>
    </form>
```

I want to post only inputs that the checkbox up on them is checked.
For example, if I check checkbox with `id="checkbox_m"` when I click on submit only input with `id="m"` would send.

Comment: hello, in order to get answers to your questions you must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use name attribute in checkbox eg `<input type="checkbox" value="add"  name="m" id="checkbox_m">`

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle input by checkbox value. disabled inputs wouldn't send.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(checkbox){

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
    document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name='+checkbox.id+']').disabled = checkbox.checked;
  });

});
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
        
  <input type="checkbox" id="m">
  <input type="text" name="m">

  <input type="checkbox" id="n">
  <input type="text" name="n">

  <button type="submit" id="button">Send</button>

</form>
```

It used checkbox `id` as input `name` to find that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution to send each data that want :

```
$("#request").on("submit", function(e){

    // here check if checkbox_m is checked push input m value to data
    // here check if checkbox_n is checked push input n value to data

        $.ajax({
          url: '',
          type: 'post',
          data: data,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data)
          }
        });
});
```

Change `form` to this :

```
<form action="" id="request">
```

So you can determine which data want to send before sending request.
Don't forget to add jQuery to your app.